# X509Store.Add/Remove OS synchronization

Tags: c#, windows, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to add certificate to current user certificate store and immediately after it read it from other application. so, what I am doing is

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(...//binary certificate here){
  PrivateKey = myPrivateKey
};

var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
store.Add(new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet));
store.Close();
store = null;

cert.Reset();
cert = null;
```

After finish of this operation application is still on and doing other things, but it is not always possible to find this certificate in store. 
However, if we'll wait for 1/2 minute, we'll find this certificate for sure!

What is wrong? Isn't it possible that X509Store.Add is not synchronous operation and maybe after all closed and disposed there is still things Windows doing to complete the import process?

Comment: Same problem here today, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @LeonardoCooper yes, the fastest solution is to export the key into pfx file and then load and create certificate from file itself rather then from it content.
The other solution is to completely cleanup all related certificates from store and then import it as usual.
I am not sure why those methods work, but they do.